# How do you programmatically do initial setup to a UITableViewCell created as a storyboard prototype?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a bunch of different cells created as prototypes in a storyboard, but I have changes that apply to all cells of that type, so I only want to do them once. But I don't think I can apply these changes in storyboard, so I have to do them programmatically.

e.g. modifications to the CALayer of an image view in the cell, setting a custom font on a label etc etc,.

Seems wasteful to have to redo this every time the cell recycles, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to check if the cell is new or recycled anymore, because the cell is never nil.

I suppose you could add a manual flag that indicates whether the cell is new or not, seems like a hack though. Any other options?

EDIT: Not even sure if you could use a manual flag, because where would you initialize it?

Comment: jrturton is right. Subclass UITableViewCell and put your customisation in `awakeFromNib`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform one-time setup of the cell in `awakeFromNib`. However, I imagine you're talking about replacing the code that used to go into the `if (cell == nil)` block in your table view datasource.

I would first try to move this code into your cell. Does it really belong in the table view controller, or is it more appropriate inside the cell itself?

If that isn't appropriate, then the "best" solution I've found is to check for some property on the cell after dequeuing, and if this is not present, do my initial setup, which involves setting the property. It does feel like a hack though.

Comment: Where in the cell? Its init method?

Comment: No, in awakeFromNib, as I say at the top of the answer.